# Installing Windows on Second Storage

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive

I have a problem when I try to install windows on my second hard disk.

I'm using a pc portable and Actually Ubuntu 22.04.2 on my first hard disk but I have also Ubuntu on my second hard disk.
To install windows I have an external hard-disk Seagate 2tb.
I've tried to read other questions but they are incomplete or difficult (for me) to understand.

I have actually downloaded the windows.iso but when I try to copy it on the hard disk I receive an error message telling me: `Error splicing file: File too large1`

I ask you please to write to me all the steps that I have to do, I need them to work and I have a lot to do.

if possible i would like to do:

1. remove Ubuntu from second hard-disk
2. install windows 10 on my second hard-disk (indicate to me the best win key to buy)
3. have Ubuntu on my first Account
4. Have the possibility to choose which account I can run at the start

secondary importance:
5. Solving that error message that doesn't let me update (sudo apt-get update)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need the "Windows 10 Media Creation Tool". You can find it on the search engine of your choice. Before you have to format the installation media as FAT32. Not NTFS and also not exFAT.

Comment: @zomega Outdated. As of now, for UEFI mode only, users can simply extract the ISO to a 8GB+ flash drive formatted as NTFS or exFAT, not FAT32. And even when "burning" the ISO the file system of the target drive, as long as recognized by the OS and made available, is irrelevant becauzse it'll be replace by the ISO9660.

Comment: @kevin You're asking about a trivial dual-boot which is very well documented. That said, the incorrect terminology you used suggests you aren't familiar with a Windows installation, UEFI mode and its requirements, or with partitioning, all of this being fundamental to do it successfully. I suggest you start reading https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi which is the other way around (Windows installed first) but the same concepts apply.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Are you sure? I think many UEFI firmwares can only read FAT32 but not exFAT nor NTFS.

Comment: @zomega Yes, I am. This has been often commented by the expert oldfred at AskUbuntu. To be clear it doesn't work for BIOS/Legacy mode but UEFI just needs the EFI folder and yes, now and since many editions ago, it must be in a file system that support >4GB files due to the non-standard Microsoft ISOs. An old tool for burning specifically Windows ISOs in Linux strictly required formating as NTFS and the multi-boot tool Ventoy uses exFAT so we know both work. MKUSB also deals with the new ISOs by extracting the contents: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive

Comment: I've tested Ventoy with both Linux and Windows ISOs inside in current PCs and as old as 2013-14 machines and all could read the EFI folder in exFAT and chainload to the select ISO perfectly.

Comment: @ChanganAuto On the link you posted they say you cannot extract the ISO because FAT32 doesn't not support files larger than 4GiB. So even they say you have to use FAT32. I can confirm that. UEFI officially doesn't support exFAT nor NTFS: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFI_system_partition#Format_the_partition I believe you that there may be motherboards supporting exFAT or NTFS. But to be sure I recommand to use FAT32 only. And because FAT32 doesn't support large files you cannot simply extract the ISO.

Comment: No, they don't say what you think they say :-) And facts are facts. Ventoy works (exFAT) and so does this https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB (FAT32 where doable, mandatory NTFS for the new non-standard ISOs). @kevin for assured results try Ventoy: Follow the instructions to install it in any sufficient USB flash drive then simply copy the downloaded Windows ISO of you choice to the root of the drive. It can't be more simple than that unless you're downloading it with Windows that then triggers the automatic use of the official Media Creation Tool.